# Random Forest limitation of 53 categories

Tags: categorical-data, fitting, many-categories

Since Random Forest has limitation of 53 categories, which categorical model can be applied to categorical data with vectors which have 100K+ levels?

```
# 'data.frame': 10000000 obs. of  31 variables:
#  $ id            : Factor w/ 123753 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# etc. ...
```

Comment: Is your variable really categorical? 100k+ is a huge number of levels.

Comment: Yes it is. It is the ID.

Comment: You might want to expand a bit on what your data looks like, it will be hard to help if we don’t know what it is you’re trying to predict and with what you have available to predict it

Comment: I have users (`id` as a factor with 123753 levels) and about 25 logical variables, which recognize the situation. Also I have couple numeric variables for quantitive definition of situation. I need to predict the reaction of user, by previously recorded reaction.

Comment: You might want to re-structure your data and remove `id` from the modeling variables since itself doesn't carry information. My way to go is to structure your data so that each `id` takes one line and all related variables are to be somehow aggregated.

Comment: @YilunZhang Do you mean, I definitely should replace user by his behavioral model?

Comment: @RubenKazumov You are introducing information that's not in your original post, what is a "behavioral model"?

Comment: @YilunZhang I can't add more information in the original post, because I can't edit edit it no more. But I understood, that I can't avoid the "53 categories" restriction for the variable. By the way, I have read the model with "C45 trees" can be applied to application like this, but I can't find information how to apply this kind of model in `caret::`

Comment: You can use a neural network. It is pretty efficient in multiclass problems. You will need to think more about feature enginering compared to tree models.